# Number of different valid passwords of length n with some constraints, at least one upper case letter

Tags: security, passwords

Consider the following password policy: a valid password is one where each character in the password is either a lower-case letter (a-z) or an upper case letter (A-Z), and there must be at least one upper case letter in the password. Given n ≥ 1, how many different valid passwords of length n are there?

I know for A-Z, there are 26 possibilities for each character,
and same goes for a-z.

So, if there is at least 1 upper-case letter will be 26^1 + 52^2 + ... + 52^n ?

I am not good in mathematics, and tried Google about it but still could not solve this question. I am a beginner in Computer Security module, please assist me.

Thank you in advance.

*This is a mathematics question not a programming/coding question*

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - as you already pointed out, the question is off topic and won't be received well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are 52 possibilities for each character.  For n characters, that means 52^n possible combinations without the constraint.  Of these, 26^n are all lower case letters and thus violate your constraint.  So your answer is 52^n - 26^n.

But honestly, this question is of little practical value.  99.9% of people do not choose their passwords randomly amongst the set of possibilities.  Instead, most will choose their password as having exactly one upper case letter (usually the first or the last) and the remaining lower case.  So don't let the mathematics give you a false sense of confidence!